# URL strip "#section" part of url adress

Tags: python, url, strip

I have 3 urls and I want to strip (get rid of) the part behind the actual url (These urls point to the same page, but to a different section. I want to strip the "section" part of a url):

```
url1 = "https://python.iamroot.eu/install/index.html#alternate-installation-the-home-scheme"
# wanted output: https://python.iamroot.eu/install/index.html

url2 = "https://python.iamroot.eu/install/index.html#alternate-installation-unix-the-prefix-scheme"
# wanted output: https://python.iamroot.eu/install/index.html

url3 = "https://python.iamroot.eu/install/index.html"
# wanted output: https://python.iamroot.eu/install/index.html
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I found solution.

```
print(url1.split("#")[0])
print(url2.split("#")[0])
print(url3.split("#")[0])
```

Sorry for wasting your time.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to use the `urllib.parse` library which is safer than trying to split it yourself:

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse

url1 = "https://python.iamroot.eu/install/index.html#alternate-installation-the-home-scheme"

newurl = urlparse(url1)._replace(fragment='')
print newurl.geturl())
# https://python.iamroot.eu/install/index.html
```

Answer (score 0):

A good way of doing this can be to use regex. It is an amazing tool with widespread application in many languages

```
import re
url=''#the url you want to strip
stripped_url = re.findall(".*.html", url)[0]# the stripped url
```

[Here you can see the documentation of regex](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)